# Creating an array populated with HTML code

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, cocoa-touch, xhtml

I am trying to create a `UITableView` that lists each teacher in my school and acts as a link to each teacher's web page.

I have taken the HTML code off of the webpage and not have the list of teachers and page URLs.

To ensure privacy, the list code I am showing you is not real and the names and site addresses have been changed. It is an example, but is equivalent to what I am trying to do.

The list code is:

```
<div class="field-element"> <select name="" class="form-select launcher" id="" ><option value="0">-Select-</option><option value="/subsite/teacher/714">LastName, Firstname</option><option value="/subsite/teacher/286">LastName2, FirstName2</option><option value="/subsite/teacher/734">LastName3, FirstName3</option><option value="/subsite/teacher/513">LastName4, FirstName4</option></select>
```

with the `/subsite/teacher/...` code being the teacher page link appended to the URL `www.website.com` (resulting in `www.website.com/subsite/teacher/...` and the actual name of the teacher following that URL code in the HTML.  This cycle repeats for each teacher.

How can I create an array of each teacher and the corresponding link for a `UITableView` from that HTML code? The `UITableView` would display the teacher's name in the format LastName, FirstName and when that cell is clicked, a `UIWebView` will open the corresponding web page.

Some example code would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Understand that the number of teachers could fluctuate, so it is not safe to assume the same number of teachers and the same names each time.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there some way you can contact the website administrator and arrange that they'd return you a JSON or XML object containing the list of teachers?

Comment: It could be done. Would I access that through some sort of URL?

Comment: It would look like this for instance: https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552. You send a request, receive a response with JSON object in it. Use SBJSON to convert JSON to NSDictionary and use the contents of the dictionary in your table view.

Comment: Eugene is correct. Sending the data in JSON format is a good way to send the data. However, you do not need to use SBJSON, as apple has now implemented JSON into Xcode already using the NSJSONSerialization class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general outline of the code could go this way:

- Get the data from the site.
- Parse the data to get each web-site. For this the easiest in my opinion is to use the `NSString` class and probably using the `componentSeparatedByString:`.
- Generate an array of models or data-sources for the `UITableView` and populate it. Consider on the development of your model that you should not only include the name of the teacher but also the web-site as a property of that object.
- Implement the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method to respond to each cell by pushing a `UIWebView` initialized at the site corresponding to the teacher's website.

Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str=[your HTML];
int loc1=[str rangeOfString:@"value=" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])].location;
int loc2= [str rangeOfString:@">" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(loc1, [str length])].location;
NSString *teacherSite=[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(loc1, loc2)];
```

this will give you teacher site link , do the same for the rest.